# INSTDRV.EXE for Windows 7

Tags: device-driver, legacy

Need to install non-PNP kernel device driver under Windows 7. Old reliable INSTDRV.EXE fails on StartService, claiming "2 -- system cannot find the file specified" although fully qualified path to driver SYS file is absolutely positively accurate. I realize Device Manager has an "install legacy driver" Action menu item, but that requires identifying a specific device, which I don't have. Why doesn't INSTDRV.EXE work under Windows 7? How can I install a non-PNP kernel device driver under Windows 7? Thanks.

Comment: 64-bit vs 32-bit?  Driver signing?

Comment: Even if it's a root enumerated driver (does not control any hardware) it still needs to install with an INF.  Does your driver have a test signature?  Is test signing enabled on your system?

Comment: Marko: testing is on 32 bit system. No signing [yet].

Comment: David: to the best of my knowledge, and I've been writing Windows drivers since original WinNT, legacy [non-PNP] drivers do NOT use INF, but install using INSTDRV.C from old DDK. No signature. No test signing enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, on modern Windows you have to write .inf file. Read this [short MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/hardware/ff544221(v=vs.85).aspx). 
There is a [tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842(v=vs.85).aspx) in WDK that helps installing drivers. Just copy it to your driver's folder and run it.

Update:
After submitting this answer I've found another way of installing non-pnp drivers. There is another tool, DevCon. It can be found among other WDK tools (Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64). Just copy DevCon.exe to your driver's folder and execute like this:

```
devcon.exe install pcscgate.inf Root\pcscgate
```

Root\pcscgate - device identifier that matches the one in [Model] section of .inf file (yes, you still need that file). DevCon creates an empty device node with this identifier and then installs driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now, finally solved it by setting Linker/Input/Ignore All Default Libraries to Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB).